# Нужно заставить Discord бота на python читать txt документ с айди пользователей и сравнивать их с айди автора сообщения

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Я решил привести пример с командой clear. У меня есть текстовый документ, в котором хранятся айди пользователей, которые могут пользоваться всеми функциями бота. Документ выглядит вот так:

```
123123498992302 #айди первого пользователя
294188943112399 #айди второго пользователя
123341321451234 #айди третьего пользователя
```

Я использую коги, поэтому мой код выглядит так:

```
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def clear(self, ctx, limit):
        if ctx.author.id == adminid:
            await ctx.message.delete()
            limit = int(limit)
            deleted = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit)
            cofirmdelete_embed = discord.Embed(title='Почистил чат', description=f'Удалил {len(deleted)} сообщений в #{ctx.channel}', color=0x4fff4d)
            await ctx.channel.send(embed=cofirmdelete_embed, delete_after=10.0)
        else:
            await ctx.channel.send('</ERROR: Эта команда доступна только пользователям из админлиста>')
```

Я не очень умею работать с with open(), поэтому чтение файла и взятие айди для админлиста выглядят так:

```
with open("adminlist.txt","r", newline = "\n") as f:
    adminid = f.readlines()
```

Весь вопрос в этой строчке `if ctx.author.id == adminid:` и в том, как мне сделать нормальное чтение txt файла и взятие оттуда айди админов бота, чтобы нормально сравнивать их с айди автора сообщения.
Ошибок в терминале не выдает, но пишет *"</ERROR: Эта команда доступна только пользователям из админлиста>"*, так как я задал параметр else для случая, если айди автора не совпадает с одним из айди пользователей из админлиста. (Естественно, моё айди есть в админлисте, но он пишет, что нет, так как неправильно читает txt файл)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f.readlines()` считывает отдельные строки файла в список, а это значит, что переменная `adminid` имеет следующее значение:

```py
['123123498992302', '294188943112399', '123341321451234']
```

Идентификаторы хранятся именно в виде `str`, а не `int`, т.к. из файла считывается именно текст.

Таким образом, когда вы выполняете это сравнение

```py
if ctx.author.id == adminid
```

Вы фактически сравниваете **`список строк`** и **`число`**, то есть

```py
['123123498992302', '294188943112399', '123341321451234'] == 1234567890...
```

---

Думаю, понятно, почему проверка на админа не проходит корректно.

Чтобы решить проблему, достаточно сделать 2 действия:

1. Привести все элементы списка к числовому типу `int`:

```py
with open("adminlist.txt","r", newline = "\n") as f:
    # [123123498992302, 294188943112399, 123341321451234]
    adminid = list(map(int, f.readlines()))
```

2. Проверять именно **наличие `id` в списке**, а не **равенство со списком**

```py
if ctx.author.id in adminid:
    . . .
```

---

Ну, а вообще, чтобы не возиться со считыванием файла и приведением типов, можете научиться работать с модулем `json`.

Тогда сохранить данные можно будет так:

```py
import json

data = [123123498992302, 294188943112399, 123341321451234]

with open('file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4))
```

А считать так. *Причем, считается сразу же список чисел*.

```py
import json

with open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

Разумеется, можно организовывать более сложное хранение данных, типа список списков или словарей.